# How bitcoin node server establishes outbound connections to other full nodes

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli

I installed bitcoin-core (https://bitcoin.org) on my server and run it as testnet. After that I tried to create a new testnet address "miYAFfw8xFEj2VCKKsMCu5L4uCEvC73xh5" at this page:
http://tpfaucet.appspot.com. 
The problem is I don't see the address "miYAFfw8xFEj2VCKKsMCu5L4uCEvC73xh5" on my bitcoin server. I tried with RPC command:
bitcoin-cli getaddressesbyaccount "ngoc_wallet1" 
But the result is empty object.

this my bitcoin.conf:

```
 rpcuser=bitcoinrpc
 rpcpassword=TMPP4iDWrcGMsyhZC2byTW6pb4rHcz4xK17gkKFQ4wnY

 # server=1 tells Bitcoin to accept JSON-RPC commands. 
 server=1

 # Run on the test network instead of the real bitcoin network. 
 testnet=1
```

I'm not sure what settings should I need to do more.

I would like to have synchronize bitcoin data from bitcoin network continuously. Please help me to know how the bitcoin server can accept inbound connection bitcoin data from others full node?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you created an account/wallet on that website. Just forget about that.

Instead open your own bitcoin-qt, click Receive and copy/paste the address specified there to the faucet website.

In general you always want to be the owner of Bitcoins yourself, not create accounts on websites.